# NetBIOS packet probing (port 137). Does it come from the router?

Tags: networking, firewall, internet-security, netbios, spoofing

For quite a while my machine's firewall has been detecting strange packets, seemingly coming from my router. I cannot explain this behavior. I suspect that somehow an attacker from the outside is smuggling those packets by either spoofing the source IP address or having hacked my router, but I need to confirm it. Or maybe the router is preconfigured to do this by the manufacturer?

If anyone has an idea what might be the reason, I would be very thankful.

Config:
Router/**RR.RR.RR.RR** - Arris WTM652B (I think it is Touchstone under the hood), firewall enabled.

My host/**MM.MM.MM.MM** with iptables

I get two types of unexpected packets:

- **DST Port 137 (NetBIOS)** packets coming from router's IP. Does the router have some weird "extras" with NetBIOS, or is it an outsider?
- Invalid unsolicited packets with !!??!! **SRC Port=443**, coming from various IP addresses, allocated to Google Inc. Can this be a hacking attempt? Someone (possibly Google?) trying to get through my firewall via dynamic rules on my firewall (when I search Google those rules punch a hole and someone tries to sneak in through this hole)?

Here is a sample:

```
Apr 27 10:55:38 notebook kernel: iptables REJECT input: IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC=(my LAN MAC addr) SRC=RR.RR.RR.RR DST=MM.MM.MM.MM LEN=78 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=4108 PROTO=UDP SPT=2092 DPT=137 LEN=58 
Apr 27 10:55:42 notebook kernel: iptables REJECT input: IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC=(my LAN MAC addr) SRC=RR.RR.RR.RR DST=MM.MM.MM.MM LEN=78 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=4109 PROTO=UDP SPT=2092 DPT=137 LEN=58 
Apr 27 10:55:49 notebook kernel: iptables DROP input/invalid: IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC=(my LAN MAC addr) SRC=216.58.212.4 DST=MM.MM.MM.MM LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=58408 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=53474 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0 
Apr 27 10:55:50 notebook kernel: iptables DROP input/invalid: IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC=(my LAN MAC addr) SRC=216.58.201.195 DST=MM.MM.MM.MM LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=55 ID=32104 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=34440 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0 
Apr 27 10:58:27 notebook kernel: iptables DROP input/invalid: IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC=(my LAN MAC addr) SRC=172.217.20.142 DST=MM.MM.MM.MM LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=59 ID=16097 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=38786 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Very best thanks,
mbax

Comment: I feel it would help if you told us more about your router's config, because the forwarding of NetBIOS from the WAN would normally not take place there. As for `https`, a router will usually not open its firewall for traffic initiated _from_ a certain remote _source_ port, and there's not much that anybody can do against that. One question is, are there other LAN clients, and the other is, could you use a tool such as `wireshark` to better figure what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for answering Class Stacker. The router config is rather simple in the UI, unfortunately. It has a simple radio button, saying "Firewall on" and "Firewall off". Mine is "on". I do not have any open services or port forwarding. I also checked externally and no TCP ports are open.
About the second issue: no, my machine is alone in the LAN.
I tried using tcpdump, but it did not tell me so much more than the firewall log. I'll try with wireshark.

Comment: The first packet type ( http://pastebin.com/UeH12zMq ) - it is a NetBIOS name query. The "router" (or someone else) is sniffing to see who is on the network. Is this normal?
It seems regarding the second type a TCP connection reset is sent by google ( http://pastebin.com/GQW9YeiX ). Can it be that this is due to my HTTPS sessions in the browser? Why RST, those connections should end with a normal FIN, imo.

Comment: I found a similar thread relating such packets to AJAX responces by the website (Facebook in their case): http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/73344/is-it-safe-to-ignore-dos-attacks-on-my-router
They don't seem very sure though.

Answer (score 0):

I would not be worried about a NetBIOS name query coming from my router.

I've seen many routers that when you go into their MAC filtering options (or any option that works using MAC addresses) will also show the NetBIOS name that has been set on that PC. This makes it easier to work out what machines are yours on the network and restrict them as necessary.

If you are still uncertain then what I would do is go to grc.com and use their [Shields Up!](https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?bh0bkyd2) tools to scan your ports and make sure that port 137 is closed on the internet side of your router.  This way you can be sure that the name probe packets are coming from your router itself and not the internet at large.

Comment: Yup, I haven't thought of that. Indeed the router seems to be able to pick up symbolic names (at least when the firewall is not blocking the stuff - e.g. for pads, phones or Windows devices.) This makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I found [a very similar thread](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/57938/is-my-isp-doing-a-port-scan-on-my-computer) with a very understandable answer:

> As a side note, I am seeing such behaviour too on some of my servers with certain ip ranges. They are all RST packets that are sent because the DNS rotation of some commonly used webservice is containing ip addresses that do not actually have a service running.

To recap, what probably happens is due to Google's clusters and changing IP addresses, also multiple javascript requests via AJAX. Some of those Google servers probably are down and send a RST (after having switched the IP?)

Other possibility is a misconfiguration in the firewall rules or a firewall bug. I used the official iptables configuration guide and used the rules almost 1:1 so this should not be the case, but who knows?

And third - it can be an unsolicited packet, sent directly to my router with SRC IP=router ip and DST IP=my ip. The router might be so dumb to not drop those invalid packets. I would be surprized if it was like this.

If someone has a better explanation, please help.